# How to print model fields as json output?

Tags: python, django

**views.py**

```
def districts_list(request):
    obj_districts_list = Districts.objects.all()
    data = serializers.serialize(
        'json', obj_districts_list, fields=('district_name'))

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

**models.py**

```
class Districts(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    district_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.ForeignKey('States', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.district_name)
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: Output is JSON format]

But i just want the fields inside the Accounts.districts as output in JSON format.

Comment: The output that i get JSON format but i want fields inside the Accounts.districts as JSON output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `QuerySet.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) to retrieve the fields you're interested in as dicts, then pass this to `json.dumps()`, ie:

```
>>> qs = User.objects.values("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "userprofile__nickname")
>>> print(json.dumps(list(qs), indent=2))
[
  {
    "username": "toto", 
    "first_name": "", 
    "last_name": "", 
    "email": "toto@example.com", 
    "userprofile__nickname": "Toto le toto"
  }, 
  {
    "username": "root", 
    "first_name": "Root", 
    "last_name": "Root", 
    "email": "root@example.com", 
    "userprofile__nickname": "Root"
  }, 
]
```

Depending on your models fields, you may have to [provide a custom JSONDecoder subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) for datetimes and other types not directly handled by the default `JSONEncoder`.